# Nginx configuration for PhalconPHP tutorial

Tags: nginx, phalcon

I am trying to set up ngnix with a PhalconPHP framework tutorial which they have provided a structure of:

**tutorial/.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

**tutorial/public/.htaccess**:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Another folder is `app` which contains the folders: `controllers`, `models` and `views`. Now this tutorial runs perfectly on apache but on nginx , I have tried different rules which are not working. Basic config of my ngnix is:
**server config**:

```
server {
   listen  80;
   server_name localhost;  
   root C:/nginx/html;  
   location /tutorial {  
     rewrite ^/tutorial/(.*)$ /tutorial/public/$1 break;  
     try_files $uri $uri/ /tutorial/public/index.php?q=$uri&$args;  
   }  
   location /tutorial {  
      root C:/nginx/html;  
      index index.php;  
      rewrite ^/tutorial/(/.*)$ /public$1 break;  
      try_files $uri $uri/ /tutorial/public/index.php?$args;  
   }
}
```

Can anyone please help me in setting up the location rules for this tutorial on nginx.I even converted those .htaccess rules into nginx rules online, but I don't know where I am  wrong.

Comment: I think your nginx config is incomplete here, does have `location` statement in it? only this two parts? & i suggest you to visit main docs [here](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/nginx.html) .

Comment: No that is complete, i have just given my root path.I just want to know about location rules which i apply for this folder structure on phalcon framework

Comment: OK, if you have using php-fpm with your nginx for php interpreting you can use main docs, that i mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: Sorry, I think i should be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using `Windows` within nginx & want to use phalcon
So you can install [`PHP - FastCGI on Windows`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfastcgionwindows/) Then using main PhalconPHP nginx config that included in docs [here](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/nginx.html).
It might be like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root C:/nginx/html/tutorial/public;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?_url=$1;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
       fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

       include        fastcgi_params;
    }


    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root C:/nginx/html/tutorial/public;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Try above config.

Comment: Wow.. that is working..Now i am getting exception handler message, but that is another thing.Only a slight change.. since my php-cgi.exe is configured on 127.0.0.1:9000, i had to change the port. Many Many thanks